# Blocking all usb device in ubuntu, excluding certain usb device

Tags: 18.04

i am using UBUNTU 18.04 , i have to block all external USB devices into my UBUNTU system,excluding certain USB devices.

Answer (score 3):

[USBGuard](https://usbguard.github.io/) software framework helps to protect your computer against rogue USB devices by implementing basic whitelisting and blacklisting capabilities based on device attributes. To enforce the user-defined policy, it uses the USB device authorization feature implemented in the Linux kernel since 2007.

By default, USBGuard blocks all newly connected devices and devices connected before daemon startup are left as is.

A quick way to start using USBGuard to protect your system from USB attacks is to first generate a [policy](https://github.com/USBGuard/usbguard#initial-policy) for your system. Then, start the usbguard-daemon  with the command `sudo systemctl start usbguard.service`. You can use the `usbguard` command-line interface command and its `generate-policy` subcommand ( `usbguard generate-policy` ) to generate an initial policy for your system instead of writing one from scratch. The tool generates an allow policy for all devices currently connected to your system at the moment of execution.<sup>**1**</sup>

#### Features

- [Rule language](https://usbguard.github.io/documentation/rule-language.html) for writing USB device authorization policies

  The target of a rule specifies whether the device will be authorized for use or not. Three types of target are recognized:

  - allow - authorize the device
  - block - deauthorize the device
  - reject - remove the device from the system
- Daemon component with an IPC interface for dynamic interaction and policy enforcement
- Command line and GUI interface to interact with a running USBGuard instance
- C++ API for interacting with the daemon component implemented in a shared library

<sup>**1**</sup><sub>Revised from: [Built-in protection against USB security attacks with USBGuard](https://rhelblog.redhat.com/2017/08/03/built-in-protection-against-usb-security-attacks-with-usbguard/)</sub>

To install USBGuard in Ubuntu <s>17.04</s> 18.04 and later, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install usbguard
```